# dc.js line chart - Date Value issue

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

Okay, so I created a basic line chart where x = months and y = values as per the below CSV:

```
dates,purpose,num
01/04/2015,Commute,1
01/05/2015,Commute,15
01/06/2015,Commute,48
01/07/2015,Commute,4
01/08/2015,Commute,4
01/09/2015,Commute,52
01/10/2015,Commute,163
01/11/2015,Commute,222
01/12/2015,Commute,126
01/01/2016,Commute,174
01/02/2016,Commute,11
01/03/2016,Commute,15
01/04/2015,Walk,0
01/05/2015,Walk,600
01/06/2015,Walk,13
01/07/2015,Walk,1
01/08/2015,Walk,1
01/09/2015,Walk,14
01/10/2015,Walk,44
01/11/2015,Walk,60
01/12/2015,Walk,34
01/01/2016,Walk,47
01/02/2016,Walk,3
01/03/2016,Walk,900
```

HTML is as follows:

```
<head>
    <title>dc.js - Line Chart Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/dc.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="test"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/crossfilter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/dc.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var Chart5 = dc.lineChart("#test");
    d3.csv("morley3.csv", function(data) {

    var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y");
    var numberFormat = d3.format(".2f");

    data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.dd = dateFormat.parse(d.dates);
    d.month = d3.time.month(d.dd);
    //d.day = d3.time.day(d.dd);
    //d.year = d.dd.getFullYear();
    //d.num = +d.num;
    //d.purpose = d.purpose;
    });

    var facts = crossfilter(data);
    var dateDimension = facts.dimension(function(d) {return d.month;});

    var dateDimension2 = facts.dimension(function(d) { if (d.purpose == "Walk") {return d.month;}});
    var numberByDate2 = dateDimension2.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.num; }); 

    minDate = dateDimension2.bottom(1)[0];
    maxDate = dateDimension2.top(1)[0];

    Chart5
    .renderArea(true)
    .width(900)
    .height(300)
    .renderArea(false)
    .brushOn(false)
    .dimension(dateDimension2)
    .group(numberByDate2)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]))
    //        .xUnits(d3.time.day)
    renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .elasticX(true)
    .elasticY(true)
    .legend(dc.legend().x(800).y(10).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
    .valueAccessor(function (d) {return d.value;}) // What does this do?
    .yAxisLabel("")
    .xAxis();
    dc.renderAll();
    });

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I've asked to show just "Walk" and the result is showing the months ok in the correct order.
The issue I'm having is that the first month is adding 835 to the result.
This is the sum of all "num" where "purpose" = "Commute".

See pic here: http://tinypic.com/r/qx9kih/8

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dimension accessor functions [must](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension) return naturally ordered values, and yours does not. If the values aren't naturally ordered, group calculations start randomly including incorrect records. Try changing your dimension to:

```
var dateDimension2 = facts.dimension(function(d) { return d.month; });
var numberByDate2 = dateDimension2.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
   if (d.purpose == "Walk") { return d.num } else { return 0; };
});
```

In other words, do your filtering in the sum accessor function rather than the dimension accessor function.

Comment: Hi Ethan, Thanks so much for making this approach clear. Results are now exactly as expected. It now makes sense that we need to filter the sum. Your'e help is much appreciated.

Comment: Glad it helped! It would be nice if Crossfilter yelled bloody murder when accessors act like this, but it's hard to identify exactly when this situation will occur. Unfortunately it continues to bite relatively new users on a regular basis. Will continue to think on it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not quite up to speed yet. On another point with a slightly different data set, I added a 2nd Group using the same grouping and Dimension method. Added it as a stack to the chart. It displays both lines but the scale doubles-up (on the 2nd Group) where the 1st Group and 2nd Group's months overlap (1st Group has data Apr-Sep, 2nd Group has Apr-Mar). Is this because I'm using the same Dim?

Comment: Hmmm. I think you probably need to open another question on that one. Sounds like you might be using stacked area charts?

Comment: No problem. In the meantime, if I wanted to add another line to this chart what is your recommended method?

Comment: I'd use the line chart, as you're doing. Does it work as you expect if you use .renderArea(false)?

Comment: I just realised that I was going about this the wrong way. What I really needed was a Composite chart. I thought that the "stack" option was a method to add additional lines on the same x-axis. Thanks for your help on the pre-filtering :)

Comment: Ah, sure, makes sense!